# xdg-open commands inheriting user directory

Tags: lxde, xdg-open

I've been having a fairly longstanding problem that is now preventing me from installing google-drive-ocamlfuse.

When any CLI tries to run xdg-open URL it is not able to open the link in a webbrowser.

I can replicate the bug myself:

[image]

Yields:

[image]

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10 with LXDE.

**ETA:** Looks like an LXDE-specific issue. As a workaround I was able to log back in under GNOME and xdg-open functions as expected.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest starting by running `xdg-settings get default-web-browser` in LXDE versus GNOME and noting any differences

Comment: This is a bug in xdg-open (xdg-utils), present in 19.04 thru 19.10, fixed in 20.04. Report here, https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=931822. Can be fixed user side by editing /usr/bin/xdg-open as root, making change as seen here - https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-utils/commit/31525d3855f876ddf2e29091b2e8d376f923e09e

Comment: Thank you very much, @doug. The script resolved the bug perfectly!